# tesseract package in R doesn't recognize any character

Tags: r, web-scraping, imagemagick, tesseract

I ma using R, version 3.3.2. I am trying to parse some text using new tesseract package. Image looks like this:

[image]

code is simple:

```
library(tesseract)
engine <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
text <- ocr("some_image_path.png", engine = engine)
```

Result is:

```
Too few characters. Skipping this page
```

Why it doesn't recognize any character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are `Too few characters`? There seems to be [a limit](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/ed4c4c6bf5599f8ec42e03dbbb5cde5c5a6f9d14/ccmain/osdetect.cpp#L36) of

```
const int kMinCharactersToTry = 50;
```

which is tested against, returning your error when it fails

```
// If there are too few characters, skip this page entirely.
  if (real_max < kMinCharactersToTry / 2) {
    tprintf("Too few characters. Skipping this page\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

Try again with a sample that has more than `25` characters?

Comment: Thanks. I have appended picture few times and now it works fine. Thanks.